# Unable to update collection Mongo Express Ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I'm trying to update a mongo record using ajax/JavaScript.

I've managed to add/delete records but i'm struggling with this bit.

Currently i'm getting the error 'UPDATE ... net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET'

Code attached below

users.js

```
router.put('/updateuser/:id', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('users');
var userToUpdate = req.params.id;
collection.update({ '_id' : userToUpdate }, function(err) {
    res.send((err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg:'error: ' + err });
});
```

profile.js

```
function functioName() {
var myquery = { "fullname": "Test" };

$.ajax({
        type: 'UPDATE',
        url: '/users/updateuser/' + userID,
        data: myquery,
        dataType: 'JSON'
}).done(function( response ) {
    if (response.msg === '') {
        alert('Success');
    }
    else {
        alert('Errors: ' + response.msg);
    }
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
        console.log(error);
});
```

Then I've just got an onclick event that calls the above function.

Like I said, Add and delete are working perfectly, so just an issue with updating a record.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to use $set attribute. For example,

```
collection.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { somekey: 'somedata' }}, callback);
```

Hope works for you.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. I'm now getting the response 'ERR_CONNECTION_RESET'

Comment: router.put('/updateuser/:id', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('users');
    var userToUpdate = req.params.id;
    collection.update({ '_id' : userToUpdate }, { 
        $set: { 'fullname':'Tesr' }
    });
});

Comment: That's the updated code above, I've missed off the callback you mentioned, as I wasn't sure what it should be? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Hi
Do you still get the timeout error? Have you checked your connection ?

Comment: No. After updating my code as you suggested, that error as been replaced by "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"???

Comment: I think collection.update. is not correct. It is an promise and it does not do anything for now can yom maybe try to tackle then and catch tag or use async/await